# Expo eject and react-native-firebase integration failed

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

i tired to make push notification with the normal expo notification and i could get the token but link it with firebase and couldn't send notification from backend,

then i did **expo eject** so i can use **react-native-firebase** and i did all steps in the documentation here: `https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x` and all cloud messaging and notification steps from the right sidebar but i got that error in the picture below

Note: I use wordpress as a backend to send push notification

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to eject if you are using Expo tokens ?

Maybe you can try to upgrade to Expo SDK 37 and use FirebaseCore : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-core/

Comment: Because I couldn't send notification from the backend.. if there is a way to send the notification please help

Comment: You can store the Expo Push Tokens into a database and use Expo servers to send push notifications https://expo.io/notifications // https://docs.expo.io/guides/push-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

First, Expo push notifications is much better than current V6 firebase push notifications, as it will not provide notification data to app, to make it happen, you have to do a lot of circus. If that was the only reason you are ejecting, don't do that.

Second, That error is saying you did not configure firebase properly, follow the instructions properly from the react native firebase doc.

Comment: Setting up push notifications is my only reason to eject.. because i couldn't figure out how to send it from backend.. if you have any idea of how to send notification from backend please give me a link for docs or tutorial, Thank you

Comment: ok, i have answer for that, before that, let me know which backend are you using...
for PHP simple curl request will be enough with proper format.

Comment: Now i use this with laravel https://github.com/Alymosul/exponent-server-sdk-php

Comment: That should work, but that is not really required, as you are using PHP server itself you can do simple CURL request,
as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55661278/3447642)